# Transaction.Commit saves changes made before BeginTransaction

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

What is the best way to avoid committing unwanted changes?

```
var a = session.Load<A>(id);
a.Value = ParseExpressions(a.Value);

using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
  // Do some work here
  tx.Commit();
}
```

The `A` object contains expressions which need to be evaluated before the work can be done, but when the transaction is committed `a.Value` is saved to the database.

I only want the changes which occur **after** session.BeginTransaction() to be saved.

I've tried calling `session.Clear()` but that causes entities with a Guid Id to be saved instead of updated.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I remember correctly, but you should be able to set the session.FlushMode to never, and explicitly save the changes you want to save.

Comment: That will only delay the flush, not select the changes

Answer (score 0):

You could use the event system to skip saving specific entities, but you're getting yourself in trouble.

You can also `Evict()` specific entities from the session.

The rule of thumb is: if you don't want to save a change to an entity, **don't modify the entity**. All your changes must be ready when you call commit.